# Codeigniter session only works if NOT 'sess_use_database'

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I've an upload script which once something is uploaded theres a 5 minute session inwhich the user can edit the title for their upload. It's all working fine with when the session is just a local cookie with these settings:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'if_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 300;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Now when i try to alter this to use the ci_sessions table i change 'sess_encrypt_cookie' to false and to true 'sess_use_database'.

The data now shows in the database but my session detection code doesn't find any session!

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('edit')) : ?> 
<?php $session_info = $this->session->userdata('edit'); ?>
<?php $ids_array = explode(",", $session_info['image_id']); ?>
<?php foreach ($ids_array as $id): ?>
<?php 
if ($id == $alpha_id 
&& 
$this->session->userdata('ip_address') == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] 
&& 
$session_info['session_id'] == $this->session->userdata('session_id')) :
?>
```

Can anyone see why it'd work with cookies and not now? Thanks

**more info:**
db config http://pastebin.com/qDbBQu8h

session CHECK code http://pastebin.com/cSmZqcAE

session SET code http://pastebin.com/wZf3mGW5

Comment: Can you show the `CREATE TABLE` statement you used to create your session table?

Comment: @FrancisAvila I dont have it but here's the structure if that helps http://i39.tinypic.com/29uol1h.png

Comment: Export your table with phpMyAdmin and post the structure above. You'll need to post some more info if you want help.

Comment: @Zenbait here's the structure http://pastebin.com/GLPxS6Bm I also added pastebin code to the #1 post

Comment: In your session set code, why do you call this: `$this->session->set_userdata('session_id')` ? That essentially sets session_id to nothing in your session..

Comment: @Ben What is the correct way then?

Comment: @Ben i removed "set_" from there and how this is stored in the db http://pastebin.com/JJngLvFc

Comment: Why do you bother with session_id anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
'session_id' => $this->session->set_userdata('session_id')
```

You are using set_userdata instead of userdata.

Comment: that works but now my CHECK code doesn't pickup the session, heres the user_Data in the session http://pastebin.com/JJngLvFc

Comment: very hard to tell with the code you provided can you please post the complete code.

Comment: and just for the suggestion you dont need to put this line $this->session->userdata('ip_address') == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  instead you can set $config['sess_match_ip'] to true it does the same thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

have you load codeigiter session library ? look like you not loaded session library yet, make sure load the library first from autoload.php or from you controller,

```
$this->load->library('session');
```